# When was proof of stake theorized?

Tags: mining-theory, consensus, proof-of-stake, history

Hi l've seen a while ago that Proof of stake concensus mechanism was theorized a while ago (before proof of work) in distributed systems. But I can't find any source of that, while searching 'proof of stake' on internet can only see Ethereum related stuffs. Was proof of stake theorized in 2011 or before that ? Thanks a lot

Comment: According to https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/34/3/1156/5868423, the PoS was first introduced alongside Peercoin in around 2012.

Comment: According to [King & Nadal 2012](https://www.peercoin.net/read/papers/peercoin-paper.pdf) *"A concept termed proof-of-stake was discussed among Bitcoin circles as early as 2011."* However King & Nadal seem to widely credited with the term.